# Click MouseEvent on child does not get executed because of parent MouseEvent in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, events, mouseevent

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of sortedItems; let i = index" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event, i, item)">
    <cv-checkbox [toggle]="getSelection(item._itemId)" (toggleChange)="setSelection(item._itemId)"></cv-checkbox>
</div>
```

The mousedown function looks like this:

```
onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent, index: number, item: Item) {
    this._mouseDown = true;
    this._initialMousePosition.x = event.clientX;
    this._initialMousePosition.y = event.clientY;
    this.placeholderItem = item;
    this.selected = index;
}
```

The item div is the parent with a mousedown event.

The cv-checkbox is a custom angular component. The toggleChange gets called when i click on the input in the cv-checkbox component. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" (click)="toggleChange.emit(this.toggle)" />
</div>
```

With the typescript code as follows:

```
export class CheckboxComponent {
    @Input() public toggle: boolean = false;
    @Output() public toggleChange = new EventEmitter();

}
```

But for some reason the toggleChange is not fired. When i remove the mousedown event on the parent it works just fine. 
So as you can see, there is no preventDefault() or anything. What's the reason that toggleChange doesnt get executed when clicking the checkbox, when there is a mousedown event on the parent? How can i fix this?

Comment: So you want `toggleChange` to be emitted when clicked on the *parent*?

Comment: No when i click the checkbox, `toggleChange` doesn't fire, Sorry if that wasnt clear

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, nothing. logs in the toggleChange function are not executed. The mousedown logs are executed

Comment: Where are the `toggleChange` `@Input()` and `@Output()`. Please add the code and please make it more clear what code is in what component and how they are related.

Comment: How is `onmouseDown` related to `toggleChange` anyway?

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear, i have made some edits, normally all the code is there.

`onMousedown` is not related to `toggleChange` in any way outside of the fact that it's called by a mousedown event of the parent div

Comment: did you try replacing `(mousedown)` by `(click)` ?

Comment: i can't. the mousedown is part of a drag and drop functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation() in child component and create a function eg:-

```
<div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" (click)="child($event)" />
</div>

child(e) {
    this.toggleChange.emit(this.toggle)
    e.stopPropagation()
  }
```

Comment: The problem in my case is that `child($event)` will not be executed. Apparently the `(mousedown)` event prevents this? If i remove `(mousedown)` it works as intended.

Comment: create an example on plunker

Comment: If i try to recreate it in plunker it works normally. It could be that it's some other code that is preventing the code to be executed, i'm working in a really big project and i cant share all the code. Though thanks for providing an answer.